# Way for Seeing the Table relationship Tree for a Database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Friends, I am working on a issue in ERP which contains lots of Tables in it. I need to know the whole relationship between the table in a database to fix it. Is there any way to see all the Tables with their relationship among them of a database. I am using SQL Server Management Studio R2 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Open your SQL Server management studio and enter into your DB.
2. Enter into Database Diagrams and search for diagrams
3. If there is no diagram, create a new diagram (right mouse click - New Database Diagram)
4. Inside the Diagram use right mouse click, add all the relevant tables and see the relationships

   [image: stage 1]

[image: Stage 4]

You can see more info about DB Diagrams [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/)

You can see [here](http://www.xcri.org/wiki/images/b/b2/CoursesDbXcriCap1.2.png) an example for diagrams with tables and relationships

Comment: What to do if no Foreign keys exist in any table? how to generate relations then?

Comment: As far as I remember you can create relations directly from the diagram

Comment: so please write how to do that

Answer (score 2):

Use database diagrams in management studio and see whole tables and relations .